# Is there a possibility from database to interact with java class?

Tags: java, sql-server, database

I have a column containing HTTP URL's.
There is a need to check the availability of these URL's and set a flag in the next column.
Not sure how to approach this problem statement.
Can someone help me with this!

Comment: ***database to talk to java class***....what???

Comment: Write an code to fetch that URL and make http request to that, than you need to check response status code , based on that you can update your database

Comment: I know i can do a batch process for the same.but is there a possibility that database can talk to java class? its just a thought process.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Apache Velocity engine can talk to java class. In the similar way why can't we have databases talking to java class? looking for the possibility

Comment: Your code should be "talking" to database, not vise versa, especially in your case.

Comment: In SQL Server you can use CLR to compile something that the database could use to check URL's. But it's a bad idea. And I think you can only write them in .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java classes do not talk. There is a JVM process running on some hardware; and that does execute Java classes "running inside" of it.

So in essence, your database would have to **reach out** to some external service that validates URLs. And it wouldn't really matter if that service is implemented in Java, or any other language.

But to me that sounds like a bad idea. You should consider doing the reverse: an external service that (maybe routinely) retrieves URLs from your database; checks if they are still valid, and then updates your "flags" as required.

Besides: checking URLs, is in itself is not exactly an easy task, as in: is an URL really *down* if the site is maybe offline during the 5 seconds you check it today?! You need to come up with some good heuristics there.